# How to make newsticker scroll smoothly while fading pictures

Tags: javascript

On the website, there are a slideshow with fading pictures and on the bottom a newsticker that scrolls horizontally. Both are animated with javascript.
What bugs me is that on the beginning of ever picture fade, the newsticker stops scrolling for a short moment. This seems to be heavily dependent on the resources available to the browser.

How can I make both scripts run smoothly?

This is the code used to fade the pictures:

```
this.b_slidenow = function(){
    var check1,maxalpha,curralpha;
    check1=ptofade.style.MozOpacity;
    maxalpha=(100-factor*u)/100*105;
    if(check1<=maxalpha/100){u=u+1;}
    curralpha=100-factor*u;
    ptofade.style.filter="Alpha(Opacity="+curralpha+")";
    ptofade.style.MozOpacity=curralpha/100;
    ptofade.style.opacity=curralpha/100;
    if(u<steps){ //slide not finished
        if(stopit=="0"){mytimeout=setTimeout(function(){self.b_slidenow();},ftim);}
        else {this.b_slide();}
    }
    else{ //slide finished
        if(startim<emax){
            ptofade.style.visibility="hidden";
            ptofade.style.zIndex=1;
            pnext.style.zIndex=2;
            startim=startim+1;u=0;
            mytimeout=setTimeout(function(){self.b_slide();},stim);
        }
        else{
            ptofade.style.visibility="hidden";
            ptofade.style.zIndex=1;
            pnext.style.zIndex=2;
            startim=1;u=0;
            mytimeout=setTimeout(function(){self.b_slide();},stim);
        }
    }
}
```

And this is the code used to scroll the ticker:

```
function TICKER_tick() {
    if(!TICKER_PAUSED) document.getElementById(ticker).scrollLeft += TICKER_SPEED * (TICKER_RIGHTTOLEFT ? -1 : 1);
    if(TICKER_RIGHTTOLEFT && document.getElementById(ticker).scrollLeft <= 0) document.getElementById(ticker).scrollLeft = document.getElementById(ticker).scrollWidth - document.getElementById(ticker).offsetWidth;
    if(!TICKER_RIGHTTOLEFT && document.getElementById(ticker).scrollLeft >= document.getElementById(ticker).scrollWidth - document.getElementById(ticker).offsetWidth) document.getElementById(ticker).scrollLeft = 0;
    window.setTimeout("TICKER_tick()", 20);
}
```

The site is only for an internal kiosk screen and will be rendered with chrome.

Comment: Post some code, most of us aren't fortune tellers.

Comment: I'm not familiar enough with javascript to see if there are any performance issues with this, but you can try to give this a go using jQuery, and see if it'll work smooth with that.